# php setcookie not working as expected

Tags: php, cookies

I am learning PHP now. Any one can take a look at this and see why the cookie is not set and keep showing as empty?

```
<?php

    if ($_COOKIE["name"]) {
        echo "welcome back" . $_COOKIE['name'];
    }

    else {
        $fname = $_POST["fname"];
        $age = $_POST["age"];
        if ($fname) {
            echo "your name is ".$fname;
            setcookie("name", $fname, time()+6000);
            echo "cookie" . $_COOKIE['name'];
        }

        if ($age) {
            echo "your age is " . $age;
        }
    }

?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="info.php">info</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ($fname) {
        setcookie("name", $fname, time()+6000);
        echo "your name is ".$fname;
        echo "cookie" . $_COOKIE['name'];
    }
```

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)**

*setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.*

Answer (score 3):

You probably get an `headers already sent` warning: You need to set the cookie before you send any output to the browser and you are doing an `echo` in the line before it.

So just make sure there is no output (empty lines, spaces, echoes, etc.) before you set the cookie.